# Setting position of contour sub-plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I am working on identifying tumors in CT images, using SciPy. Once I've identified the slice containing the tumor, I retrieve the slice using:

```
slice_x, slice_y = ndimage.find_objects(label_im==label)[0]
```

I then plot the full image as follows:

```
plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
```

I want to overlay the contour of the extracted slice (containing the tumor) on top of the original image in the appropriate location. However, I can't get the contour plot to lie on top of the proper region. Instead, the contour plot always lies in the top-left corner of the image. Here's what I'm using:

```
plt.contour(mask[slice_x, slice_y], position=(slice_x.start, \
slice_y.start), linewidths=2, colors='r')
```

Here is the result:

[image: CT image]

How can I set the position of the contour plot inside the main plot? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `extent` keyword argument instead of `position`.  However, you'll need to specify a maximum as well as a start (i.e. it needs to be `extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]`)

In your case, it would look something like:

```
extent=[xslice.start, xslice.stop+1, yslice.start, yslice.stop+1]
plt.contour(mask[xslice, yslice], extent=extent)
```

Note that you may need to use the `origin` keyword argument (or flip ymin and ymax) to control the way the input data is interpreted.

Alternately, you could do something like the following:

```
x, y = np.mgrid[xslice, yslice]
plt.contour(x, y, mask[xslcie, yslice])
```

It will be a bit inefficient if you're working with a large region, but it's much cleaner.

As a full example of the latter approach:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

data = np.random.random((100,100))

xslice, yslice = slice(20, 30), slice(45, 65)

plt.imshow(data, cmap=cm.gray)

x, y = np.mgrid[xslice, yslice]
plt.contour(x, y, data[xslice, yslice])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but no luck. I'm able to move the contour using `extent` (finally!), but it never lies the right place. I've tried flipping Xs and Ys, origin='upper', origin='lower', origin='image'. Both of the proposed approaches give the same (but incorrect) results. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Nevermind - got it. I was flipping the slice_x and slice_y variables. Thanks a bunch!